# CSS Table width in Rmarkdown for HTML output

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown, rstudio

I'm using CSS multiple columns in my Rmarkdown html output, so I'm using a flex display DIV that have two Columns, the first column contain a plot (width 35%),

the second column(width 65%) should contain a two column Table, the problem that this table do not have the same column size (the why and interpretation columns), I insert the table using the "Visual markdown editor",
I tried different classes (.column, .table), different style and keys (table-layout: fixed..) but with no result

Here you can find the code I'm working on and the actual result

````
::: {style="display: flex;"}
::: {.column width="35%" padding="50px"}
```{r echo=FALSE, , fig.width=12, fig.height=12}
plot()

:::

::: {.column width="65%"}
::: {.table table-layout="fixed}
| ![](alerte_p5.png) Alerte                                                         |                                           |
|:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------|
| **¿WHY?** `r definition$why[1]` | **INTERPRETATION:** `r definition$Interp[1]` |
:::
:::
````

A screenshot of my actual result:
[image: a screenshot of my actual result]

Answer (score 0):

you can add a `<style>` tag in the page (not in the visual editor of RStudio):

````
## R Markdown

::: {style="display: flex;"}
::: {.column width="35%" padding="10px"}
```{r echo=FALSE, , fig.width=2, fig.height=2}
 ggplot2::ggplot()
```
:::

::: {.column width="65%"}
::: {.table table-layout="\"fixed"}

<style>
table th:first-of-type {
    width: 10%;
}
table th:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 90%;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>



| Alerte                   | Empty                              |
|:-------------------------|:-----------------------------------|
| **¿WHY?** `r nrow(iris)` | **INTERPRETATION:** `r ncol(iris)` |
:::
:::
:::
````

[image]